# Why is it possible to have both numeric and string index signatures for an interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

According to the language specification it is possible to have an interface with both numeric and string index signature, so the following interface seems to be valid:

```
interface WeirdArray {
  [index: string]: string;
  [index: number]: string;
}
```

But I can't find a suitable example where such an interface can be used, can someone provide an example where such an interface makes sense?

Comment: To match the capabilities of Javascript upon which Typescript sits?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: I'm not sure. Everything in JS is addressable via string and integer. e.g. var stuff = []. stuff["one"] = "two".  stuff[0] is just as valid as stuff["one"] to access the value of "two".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the number indexer type has to be a subtype of the string indexer type, it's not terribly useful unless you had some crazy type where the string-named properties were of some base type and the number-named properties were a subtype of that type. I can't imagine a use for this.

In short, it's allowed because it's not *disallowed*.